# WPF Generated files won't compile

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2013

In my WPF application I add click event handler for context menu item (context menu for ListBoxItem).

When I try following approach:

```
            <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListBoxItem}}">
                    <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ContextMenu>
                                <MenuItem Header="Remove" Click="RemoveSelectedSchedule"/>
                            </ContextMenu>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                    <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="ScheduleList_MouseDoubleClick"/>
                </Style>
            </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

and try to build, build fails with following error messages:

> 1>C:\Users\Pawel\Source\Repos\academiccalendar\AcademicCalendar.Desktop\obj\Debug\MainWindow.g.cs(113,14,113,15): error CS1513: } expected
>   1>C:\Users\Pawel\Source\Repos\academiccalendar\AcademicCalendar.Desktop\obj\Debug\MainWindow.g.cs(123,19,123,20): error CS1514: { expected
>   1>C:\Users\Pawel\Source\Repos\academiccalendar\AcademicCalendar.Desktop\obj\Debug\MainWindow.g.cs(125,9,125,10): error CS1525: Invalid expression term '}'
>   1>C:\Users\Pawel\Source\Repos\academiccalendar\AcademicCalendar.Desktop\obj\Debug\MainWindow.g.cs(125,10,125,11): error CS1002: ; expected

However, if setting Click event handler is removed for Context MenuItem, code compiles and runs properly.

EDIt Event handler is currently left empty.

```
void RemoveSelectedSchedule(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Comment: Right click on the click eventhandler in XAML window and take Navigate to eventhanlder.  Look at the code there real close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is bizarre...

After some playing I got it to compile

1. Remove the code

   ```
           <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
               <Setter.Value>
                   <ContextMenu>
                       <MenuItem Header="Remove" Click="RemoveSelectedSchedule"/>
                   </ContextMenu>
               </Setter.Value>
           </Setter>
   ```
2. Compile - Fails
3. Add A Second EventSetter
4. Compile Fails
5. Add back the code

   ```
           <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
               <Setter.Value>
                   <ContextMenu>
                       <MenuItem Header="Remove" Click="RemoveSelectedSchedule"/>
                   </ContextMenu>
               </Setter.Value>
           </Setter>
   ```
6. Compile again - Compiles!!!

Something wrong with the WPF compiler ...

Edit 1 Better Answer...

If you move the ContextMenu to the resources section

```
<ContextMenu x:Key="ListBoxItemContextMenu">
            <MenuItem Header="View" Name="MenuItemView" Click="ContextClicked"/>
        </ContextMenu>
```

And access it in the Setter it seems to work

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListBoxItem}}">
                            <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource ListBoxItemContextMenu}">
                            </Setter>
                            <EventSetter Event="MouseDown" Handler="EventSetter_OnHandler1"></EventSetter>
                            <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="EventSetter_OnHandler2"></EventSetter>
                        </Style>
```

Comment: Thanks, your solution helps. Yet, it's odd behaviour, I'll investigate it in near future.